# Hello bar app makes my nav mobile collapse.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, shopify

I have a problem in my theme in Shopify, I installed an app called "Hello Bar" to display offers on all my pages. For some reason the app is not compatible with my theme, I talked with the developers of the app and they told me to add this to my CSS file in my theme:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px){

     .page-wrapper{

        position: static;

   }

}
```

That fixes the issue on the desktop but on mobile version my navigation menu is collapse and I can not close it. I added this to fix the issue:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
   .nav-mobile{
       display: none;
   }
```

but then when I click the button of the menu, the menu is blank. 
Please can someone help me, is there a trick that can fix this issue?

Comment: Can you please share  your website url. so that i can tell you how to fix.

Try this as a guess

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){

     .page-wrapper{

        position: initial;

   }

}

Comment: this is the URL: http://myintent.myshopify.com/?preview_theme_id=143300737

Answer (score 0):

Setting `display: none;` hides the element you apply it to. That is why the menu is blank.

Comment: my question is, if there other way to fix that? How can I hide the navigation menu, and then show it?

Answer (score 0):

I added this script and it didn't  work

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $( document ).ready(function() { 
     $( "#icon-hamburger" ).click(function() {
       $("#cell-phone").show();
 });
 });

</script>
```